# What is the difference between BrowserRouter(import from react-router-dom) and ConnectedRouter(import from connected-react-router/immutable)?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router/immutable';
import { BrowserRouter as Router,} from 'react-router-dom';
```

i need to know difference between above both of them.

Answer (score 13):

**ConnectedRouter** is to be used with [**Redux**](https://redux.js.org/) and can synchronize router state with a Redux store.
**BrowserRouter** is the 'standard' React router for the browser, to keep the UI in sync with the current URL.

Answer (score 7):

The main difference in `connected-react-router/immutable` in is that `history is stored in redux as immutable object` so you can timetravel your history any time in the redux-life of the application.